Array.length check issue: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '1' and '0' have no overlap
Assume having the following code in typescript:
const x = [1];

if (x.length !== 1)
throw "error";

x.pop();

if (x.length === 0)
throw "error";

the compliler weirdly complains at line if (x.length === 0) and says This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '1' and '0' have no overlap.ts(2367)
It seems after the first condition, it always assumes the length is 1 and array modifications doesn't change it. I don't understand the reason and how can we fix it?
Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA2gRgLoG4CwAofASwDMYAKOAOgBsBTMAcygAsYBCRZNASnxYCcQAdxgAiWv0H9RuAnioAHEArLdZRUhRr0mrTsgAMvPAOFiJUmUA

Short answer: function side-effect does not play well with type-narrowing, and typescript give up on that and (maybe unintentionally) encourage more functional approach.

This is one of these cases when TypeScript's type narrowing isn't the smartest. TypeScript doesn't follow .length changes through methods, so its way of narrowing the .length type to a union often does not make much sense.
Unfortunately, you need a workaround. One of them is to set the new length instead of popping:
if (x.length > 0) { // This is needed, as an error would be thrown for an empty array
    x.length -= 1; // works like x.pop() minus returning the last item
}


It is a bit weird approach and it makes the code hard to read. At this point I prefer using @ts-ignore

It's not that weird, some people prefer it that way.

I mean it is not related to the code's logic and it makes it hard to read in future. Not a good idea to add language related workaround inside biz logic code.

What's not related to the code logic?

the above code :) assume, you see the above code inside the quick_sort() function. It is hard to find out, it is not related to the sorting algorithm.

Hmm, why not? You're overwriting a length, making an array shorter. While not my favorite, I wouldn't go that far.

The following code
if (x.length !== 1) throw "error";

narrows down the type of x.length to be 1.
For the second question, type narrowing only occurs on JavaScript’s runtime control flow constructs like if/else, conditional ternaries, loops, truthiness checks, etc.

This only answer half of the question. The other half is x.length is mutated by x.pop() but why typescript does not realize x.length might have been mutated.
